# Play Framework send message via rabbit mq

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, playframework-2.2

Does anybody out there using rabbitmq with Play Framework?

I have an AI written in Scala using Play Framework. And I have a mean stack, which handles a nosql database. 
I'd like to send json messages via rabbitmq to that AI.

I already got things going with nodejs and rabbitmq, but now that i want to connect to play I might need your help.

Has someone any experience with rabbitmq and play or some practical Advices?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the official RabbitMQ Java library, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard Java library to send messages to RabbitMQ like this:

```
val factory = new ConnectionFactory()
factory.setUri(serverUri)
val channel = connection.createChannel()
channel.queueDeclare(queue, true, false, false, null)
channel.basicPublish("", queue, true, false, null, data)
```

When using this in Play, you'd probably put all the logic up to `basicPublish` inside its own class and [inject that instance into your Controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaDependencyInjection), so that you can use a persistent connection to Rabbit.

Since all your seem to be doing is taking json from a request and pushing it into Rabbit, you don't even have to deal with serialization and can just take the text body from the `Request` and pass it as the `data` payload of `basicPublish` (unless you want to perform validation of the input before passing it on).