# Play Framework with RabbitMQ

Tags: playframework, rabbitmq, jms

I want to use RabbitMQ with Play 2.5.

What's the most convinient way for beginner to do this?

Comment: This question is too broad. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question at StackOverflow. What did you tried already? Are you using Java or Scala? Which version of PlayFramework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850905/play-framework-send-message-via-rabbit-mq